# Binding Configurations to a Complex Object

Tags: json, asp.net-core-2.2, appsettings, c#-7.0

In ASP.NET Core 2.2, I'm trying to bind an array of JSON objects to a matching C# object, but it's not binding the members properly. (Spoilers: Test1 works, Test2 doesn't.)

In my appsettings.json, I have this config:

```
{
    "Test1": [
        "A",
        "B",
        "C"
    ],
    "Test2": [
        { "s": "A" },
        { "s": "B" },
        { "s": "C" }
    ]
}
```

This is pulled into the Configuration object in the Program class in a pretty standard way that's been working well for me for all other purposes.

```
public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; } = new ConfigurationBuilder()
   .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
   .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json",optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
   .AddEnvironmentVariables()
   .Build();
```

In my program, I created a class that matches the object in the Test2 array.

```
public class Test2Class
{
    public string s;
}
```

Finally, I bind them like so:

```
List<string> test1 = new List<string>();
Program.Configuration.Bind("Test1", test1);
List<TestClass> test2 = new List<TestClass>();
Program.Configuration.Bind("Test2", test2);
```

When I examine the results, this is what I get:

```
test1 = ["A", "B", "C"]
test2 = [{s: null}, {s: null}, {s: null}]
```

What do I need to do differently to bind the Test2 array correctly?

Comment: `TestClass.s` should be a **property** and not a **field**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TestClass.s` should be a **property** and not a **field**

```
public class TestClass {
    public string s { get; set; }
}
```

The following example can also be used to more conveniently get the desired types

```
List<string> test1 = Program.Configuration.GetSection("Test1").Get<List<string>>();
List<TestClass> test2 = Program.Configuration.GetSection("Test2").Get<List<TestClass>>();
```

Reference [Bind hierarchical configuration data using the options pattern](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/#bind-hierarchical-configuration-data-using-the-options-pattern)